# Dependency of Classes spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a class Customer which contains getter/Setter for another variable of Type Class.However Customer is not providing any services where there is dependency of Account class. However its required only for Getting/Setting

```
class Customer{
private Account account ;

Custmer(Account acc){
this.account=acc ;
}

//getter and setter for account 


}
```

So is Customer  independent of Account or is Customer dependent on account ?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever class A **uses** another class or interface B, then A depends on B. A cannot carry out its work without B, and A cannot be reused without also reusing B. In such a situation class A is called the "dependant" and the class or interface B is called the "dependency". A dependant depends on its dependencies.

Two classes that use each other are called "coupled". The coupling between classes can be loose or tight, or somewhere in between. The tightness of a coupling is not binary. It is not either "loose" or "tight". The degrees of tightness are continuous, not discrete. You can also characterize dependencies as "strong" or "weak". A tight coupling leads to strong dependencies, and a loose coupling leads to weak dependencies or even no dependencies in some situations.

Dependencies, or couplings, are directional. That A depends on B doesn't mean that B also depends on A.

So, As in the question itself, you said that Customer does not perform any operation using the Account class object then we can say that **Customer class object is independent or loosely coupled to Account class object.**